# Android Hilt multi-module, do I need to add plugin to each module or only app

Tags: android, dagger-hilt, multi-module, android-multi-module

This is not clearly explained in official documentation.

Do I need to add the hilt plugin to each module of my app or only to the main module (:app)?

Comment: if each layer has it`s DI classes you have to added it on each layer 
\n
if your main module responsable for DI for all layer , you will added it in main only 
and this what i do perfer (SSOT)

Answer (score -1):

Just add on main module,another module use from main module.

Comment: Not always true, as said by @Elsunhoty, your modules might have their own DI modules, therefore they require the hilt plugin (also, your modules are not always aware of the "main module" eg.: feature modules)

Comment: Ops.then im sorry about wrong answer.great job.